# Host Zend Framework 2 and PHP site one AWS Ubuntu server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, zend-framework2, virtualhost, ubuntu-14.04

I am having Ubuntu 14.04 server running on my Amazon Instance. I have a Web Application which is developed using Zend Framework 2 (Back-End) and also I am having a Pure PHP web page (Front-End). I need to host this 2 application under one server.

How can i solve this issue

Comment: What issue? There shouldn't be any problem hosting a ZF2 site and plain PHP site on the same server. You need to describe the problem you are seeing (error message etc.).

Comment: The Problem is if I create a virtual host then the link give me an error of saying "The requested URL /admin was not found on this server". I am accessing the link using the IP address and I am trying to call "http://54.186.35.138/admin"

Comment: What is your virtual host name? Did you add that name in the `etc\hosts` file? You also said that when virtual host is used, the error is displayed so is there a scenario when it works fine? Do let us know.